# Form API: Persistent values across submits?

Tags: forms

Getting started with the form API. None of the examples seem to keep and redisplay the values the user entered. E.g.,  you have a "name" field. User enters "John" and hits Submit.

If the form data is invalidated for some reason, the name field should still show "John" so he doesn't have to enter it again. Is there a setting to set for persistent values? values vs. default_values?

Drupal 7 stock install

Answer (score 1):

In the Form API, there are two separate value setters `#default_value` and `#value` where these two make different things happen when you using it
- `#default_value` set the value of your element when the form is created the first time, and if your form has an error for some reason, does not affect your element
- `#value` set element value every time the form is rendered, even when the form is created again because of some error

It is not correct to use `#value` for textfields and other input elements, use `#default_value` instead. `#value` is meant only for buttons, submits and other non input elements.
if you use `$form['#value'] = 'Name'` for input elements like textfield the value of that field always would be `Name` even if the user entered some other value for this field.

see [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

Comment: OK, upon further research I see that:

FAPI performs the correct behavior.

The reason I thought that FAPI cleared the field values was that there was no validation.

However, if validation fails, the previous values are redisplayed, both for validated and unvalidated fields.

But if validation passes, then  default values are displayed.

I guess the reason is that if validation passes, it's expected that you will redirect to another page, not stay on the same page.

When you're just starting out, though, you don't have all the logic in place to handle that.